# Code Obfuscation in android

Tags: android, obfuscation

I found somewhere this type of coding. Which obfuscation technique is apply on it.

[image]

Let's say If someone use this type

```
(DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(2131428239);
```

then i know this is id format of decimal value and it store inside **public.xml** and it refrence is in `id.xml` file. but class I can't found the Original name of class of my upper screen shot.What is the name of this Technique.and How to perform it. Any Help be appreciated.

How to use this Technique and where are the original name is save.

Comment: That looks like it came from a decompiled APK. No one would code like that. Plus, Progaurd is responsible for minify-ing the code into non human readable format

Comment: @cricket_007 So this is Sign APK generated code ?

Comment: Yes, this is most likely code which was extracted ("decompiled") from an APK, and thus some of the original id names are lost.

Comment: @JonasCz Thanks for the information.